# Insert cell's logic into another cell's logic in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column in Google Sheets where each cell contains pre-defined logic. For example, something like the second column in this table:

```
| 1     | =A1*-1    |
| 2     | =B2*-1    |
| -3    | =C2*-1    |
```

Let's say later I want to add the *same* logic to each cell in column B. For example, make it such that it looks like:

```
| 1     | =MAX(A1*-1,0)     |
| 2     | =MAX(B2*-1,0)     |
| -3    | =MAX(C2*-1,0)     |
```

What is the fastest way to do this, besides manually typing `MAX(...,0)` in each cell? Normal Sheets functions act on the value of the cell, not the logic, so I'm a bit lost.

To my knowledge there isn't a function that pipes in the logic from one cell to another ...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,IF(SIGN(A1:A)<0, A1:A*-1, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,IF(SIGN(A1:A)>0, A1:A, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: also works: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,IF(A1:A<0, A1:A*-1, 0)))`